# Concavity of maxima

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose we have the following optimization problem : $\min\limits_x kf(x) + g(x)$ where $f$ is a decreasing convex function in $x$ and $g$ is an increasing convex function. Can we say that $x^*$ is concave in $k$ (or under some extra conditions)?